# Is there any harm to overrride becomeFirstResponder in superview returning that for a uitextfield subview?

Tags: ios, uikit

Is there any harm in doing this:

```
override open func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool
{
    return entry.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

here is entry is a UITextField subview of a plain vanilla UIView that does the overriding

Comment: How would a plain vanilla view ever become first responder?

Comment: it's just a wrapper around uitextfield adding just a uilabel